# How to allow parcolumns environments in an enumerate environment?

Tags: enumerate, parcolumns

I want to make a note of my study on Japanese Language. For this, I have to enumerate some Japanese sentences and provide the translation in English for each sentence on the right side.

I use `parcolumns` as follows. But it does not seem to work. Compilation fails.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{parcolumns}{2}
    \colchunk{\lipsum[1]}
    \colchunk{\lipsum[2]}
\end{parcolumns}
%
\item 
\begin{parcolumns}{2}
    \colchunk{\lipsum[1]}
    \colchunk{\lipsum[2]}
\end{parcolumns}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

How to solve it with minimal effort? Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Will that document ever compile without the `\colplacechunks` command, even outside the enumerate environment? If I remember, you have to explicitly "place"  the chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to do it a little differently.  Something like this, perhaps:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% for: \AtBeginEnvironment
%\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{pdfcolparcolumns}% <-- improved version of parcolumns
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Put \marginpar on the "left"
\reversemarginpar 
% Create a counter
\newcounter{paranum} \setcounter{paranum}{0}
% The "paragraph number" command, put in the margin
\newcommand{\pnum}{%
  \marginpar{%
    \raisebox{-\baselineskip}{%
      \textbf{%
        [\refstepcounter{paranum}\arabic{paranum}]
}}}}

% Add the \pnum command to the start of the `parcolumns` environment
\AtBeginEnvironment{parcolumns}{\pnum}

\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}{2}
    \colchunk{\lipsum[1]}
    \colchunk{\lipsum[2]}
\colplacechunks

\pnum % <-- add paragraph number while in parcolumns env.
    \colchunk{\lipsum[3]}
    \colchunk{\lipsum[4]}
\colplacechunks
\end{parcolumns}

Outside the env.

\begin{parcolumns}{2}
    \colchunk{\lipsum[5]}
    \colchunk{\lipsum[6]}
\colplacechunks

    \colchunk{\lipsum[7]}
    \colchunk{\lipsum[8]}
\colplacechunks
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```